# Return url double encoded behind proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have configured login path:

```
 services.AddAuthorization()
         .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddCookie(options => options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"));
```

One of my actions (let's say `/go`) it is secured with `[Authorize]` attribute.

The problem problem is that when I hit mentioned action as an unauthorized user, the return url is double encoded:

```
/account/login?ReturnUrl=%252Fgo
```

It only happens when app is served behind reverse proxy (configured as follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-a-proxy-server)

When running locally or without reverse proxy, return url is built properly;

```
/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fgo
```

This causes some problems when using f.e. `LocalRedirect(returnUrl)`. I'd like to avoid decoding it explicitly.

What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your reverse proxy then? What are you using, how is it configured?

Comment: @poke - apache, just like in the like attached to my post.

Comment: @poke thanks for hint! It turned out that http -> https redirecting was an issue. I needed to Add [NE] as redirect rule to prevent double escaping. Any way, it seems that X-Forward is not working, as server should return http, not https so scheme was not taken from the header.